# Can I have two archetypes at level 6?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, archetype, retraining

I am playing level 6 fighter, and I was thinking if I could [retrain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=475) my 3 class feats to archetype feats. The trick is that we have [Free Archetype variant rule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1333) and I already have one archetype.

Will I be able to retrain class abilities if on level 2 and 4 I did not have 2 archetype feats and by the dedication's special could not get a dedication in a different archetype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not how you're describing it

The rules on retraining are that you must *have* qualified for the choices you are retraining to based on what you're retraining.

> When retraining, you generally can’t make choices you couldn’t make when you selected the original option. For instance, you can’t exchange a 2nd-level skill feat for a 4th-level one, or for one that requires prerequisites you didn’t meet at the time you took the original feat.

At level 2/4 you did not qualify to take a second Archetype, so you could not retrain your level 2/4 Class Feats into an Archetype Dedication feat.

### There's another way

In a similar amount of time, you can retrain your Class Feat at level 2 into one of your *Free Archetype* feats, meaning that at level 4 you could have chosen a second Free Archetype Feat, 'freeing' you up to take a second Dedication with your 4th level Feat and resume your Free Archetype and new Archetype feats at 6.

### The variant rule you're using notes that a GM could allow it

The Free Archetype Variant allows for GM's to waive the multi-feat restriction for the Free Archetype.

> If the group all has the same archetype or draws from a limited list, **you might want to ignore the free archetype’s normal restriction of selecting a certain number of feats before taking a new archetype. That way a character can still pursue another archetype that also fits their character.**